# How to get dates from a table while the date range is from the date belonging to another table?

Tags: mysql, query, mysql-workbench

I have a table `datedim` which has all the dates of a month in it. I have another table `attendance` that has dates on which attendance were taken. I need to write a query where i can get all the dates from the start till current. 
For eg. if attendance table has records starting from 3-Apr-2019 to 3-June-2019, i should get all the dates in between them.

Comment: Please provide sample input and output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [BETWEEN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) conditional operator to search for anything in a range. The BETWEEN operater is inclusive so will find records for the start and end dates too.

You will be able to query the `attendance` table directly:

`SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE attendancedate BETWEEN '2019-04-03' AND '2019-06-03'`

This question has some examples:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822648/how-do-i-query-between-two-dates-using-mysql

I hope that helps!

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. But the problem i am facing is i have around 100 such records of the start date and end date so i cannot apply between for 100 of such dates.
I used

where date between min(attendancedate) and max(attendancedate)

but i got error 1111.invalid use of group function.

Comment: Can you post the full query? 

Also this answer may help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727002/1111-invalid-use-of-group-function